# RecyclerView inside ViewPager is not working properly

Tags: android, tabs

I am creating an app in which I am using custum tab layout which contain a `ViewPager`. I am trying to set `RecylerView` in that `ViewPager` but the preblem is that the `RecyclerView` is not workign properly.

For example there are 3 tabs, `Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3`. Here I want to set data in `Tab 1` by default (I am fetching data from web) and each Tab will fetch data from web and set that to `recyclterView` when that Tab become active.

**Problem I am facing:**

**1 -** I am not able to set data in `Tab 1` by default.

**2 -** Sometimes Tabs are setting data sometimes not. Like `Tab 1` is not setting data when I come back from `Tab 2` but setting data when I came back from `Tab 3`.

**Here is MainActivity:**

```
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        pagerViewAdapter = new PagerViewAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerViewAdapter);

        DachshundTabLayout dachshundTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        dachshundTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                ArrayList<String> exchanges = new ArrayList<>();
                if ((Configuration.coinExchanges.get(Configuration.coins.get(position))) != null) {
                    exchanges = Configuration.coinExchanges.get(Configuration.coins.get(position));
                }
                pagerViewAdapter.updateExchanges(exchanges);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

**Here is PagerViewAdapter:**

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        exchanges = new ArrayList<>();
        View pagerLayout = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = pagerLayout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(this.activity, exchanges));
        container.addView(pagerLayout);
        return pagerLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    public void updateExchanges(ArrayList<String> exchanges){
        this.exchanges.clear();
        this.exchanges.addAll(exchanges);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Here is RecyclerAdapter:**

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.exchange_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String exchange = exchanges.get(position);
        Picasso.with(activity)
                .load(Configuration.exchangesLogo.get(exchange))
                .into(holder.exchangeLogo);
        holder.exchangeName.setText(exchange);
        new FetchData(holder, exchange).execute(
                Configuration.exchangesAPI.get(exchange));
}
```

**Here is `activity_mail.xml`. `ViewPager` is below `AppBar`:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            >

            <ImageView
                />

            <TextView
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.kekstudio.dachshundtablayout.DachshundTabLayout
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here is `pager_layout.xml`. `recyclerView` is at last:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        >

        <TextView
            />

        <TextView
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        >

        <TextView
            />

        <TextView
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using `fragments`?

Comment: @Yupi No, I have added xml files too in the question.

Comment: @NishantBhakta, did you find what was causing this issue? My data also sometimes shows and some others don't. Having a `RecyclerView` inside `ViewPager` with `TabLayout`